# Iphone - UIView not displayed

Tags: iphone, activity-indicator

I have a strange problem with a UIView :

I want to show an Activity Indicator View that I created with Interface Builder to indicate long running activity.

In the viewDidLoad function of my principal viewController I init the ActivityIndicator View like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];        
    load = [[ActivityIndicatorViewController alloc] init];
    ...
```

When I push a button it call this IBAction :

```
- (IBAction)LaunchButtonPressed{            
    // Show the Activity indicator view.
    [self.view addSubview:load.view];

    // eavy work 
    [self StartWorking];    

    // Hide the loading view.
    [load.view removeFromSuperview];    
}
```

In the StartWorking function, I ask a request to an internet serveur and parse the XML file that it return me.

The problem is that if I Call my StartWorking function, the application do not start by showing the Activity Indicator view but with the StartWorking function.
Whereas if I remove the call to StartWorking function, the view is shown.

Is someone able to explain me why? :s

Comment: Whether the view is displayed after some delay or the view in not displayed at all?

Comment: The view is displayed avec some delay.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to call the *StartWorking* method on a different thread?
Maybe its heavy process prevents other instructions to take place.

Look at the [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, especially the *detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:* method.

**EDIT**: About the pool problem, you need to create a pool in your StartWorking method, if it's called on a different thread:

```
- ( void )StartWorking
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [ [ NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init ];

    /* Code here... */

    [ pool release ];
}
```

Comment: It work fine, but all my autorelease object are leaking because there is no pool in place. :s

Comment: You should be careful doing stuff (heavy function) in threads. I usually prefer implement lightweight function in thread and let the heavy one in main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Replace :
`[self.view addSubview:load.view];`

With :
`[self performSelector:@selector(addLoadingSubview) afterDelay:0.1f];`

And create the method :
`-(void)addLoadingSubview{[self.view addSubview:load.view];}`

Comment: I'have tryed but the result is the same. I used :
   [self performSelector:@selector(ShowActivityIndicatorView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution based on santoni answer :

```
- (IBAction)LaunchButtonPressed{            
    // Show the Activity indicator view.
    [self performSelector:@selector(ShowActivityIndicatorView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

    // eavy work 
    [self performSelector:@selector(StartWorking) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];  

    // Hide the loading view.
    [load.view removeFromSuperview];    
}
```

The Activity Indicator view is dislayed before the call to the eavy function.

Thank's for answering.